# Using find to get files in subfolders with a specific name but unknown depth

Tags: regex, find, subdirectory, depth

I have a file structure like this:

```
/home/user/.m2/repository/../*SNAPSHOT/..
```

And I try to get all files in those SNAPSHOT folders, but they have a different depth. My command looks like this right now:

```
find /home/user/.m2/repository/*/*SNAPSHOT* -type f -name "*201[3-4]*"
```

but like this he only search for a depth of 1. What must I type for the `*` in my solution to get any depth of subfolders?

I tried to do some regex magic, but didn't find anything working :)

Anyone has something useful for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, I think this should work for you:

```
find /home/user/.m2/repository -path '*/SNAPSHOT/*' -type f -name '*201[3-4]*'
```

Basically the trick is to use `-path` with `find`.